# What does /static/ mean in this code?

Tags: go, static

Im trying to serve static html file in GO. 
This is how my code in main() looks like.

```
http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("/static/")))
http.ListenAndServe(":8989", nil)
```

It works but i dont understand what does static mean! Someone please explain.

Comment: This is how your folder for serving static files is defined.

Comment: Replace "/static/" with "/" and see whether your question goes away.

Comment: Alternatively you could read the godoc for the http package, which I would advise anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that whenever you handle requests that serves HTTP requests with the contents of the file system rooted at root, it try to server files declared in `http.Dir` which uses the operating system's file system implementation.

This means that whenever you access your web server index url it will try to serve files under the operating system `/static/` directory.

To serve a directory on disk under an alternate URL path you can use `StripPrefix` to modify the request URL's path before the [`FileServer`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#example_FileServer_stripPrefix) sees it.

```
http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("/your/directory/to/static/files"))))
http.ListenAndServe(":8989", nil)
```

Comment: And where is this operating system /static/ directory in ubuntu?

Comment: Are you sure you are not using relative paths?

Comment: @SimoEndre The literal `/static/` is the URL that your Go application will serve files. Those files come from (using the above answer) `/your/directory/to/static/files` - that is, anywhere you'd like.

Comment: Thanks i figured it out. Much appriciated

Answer (score 1):

Here, `/static/` is the path to the directory that will be used to serve the requests.

Depending on your setup, you proabably want to set it to a relative path instead of an absolute one…

Comment: But where is this /static/. Is it in my project file or where?

Comment: Its the physical directory on your machine…